# ListView always delete the last item

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

My list view item contains a remove button, and I set it up in my adapter to remove the item from the database. Now once that's done how can i refresh the fragment which contains the listView to remove that item? Relevant code as below:

**Remove item function in adapter:**

```
holder.actionIndicator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Delete item");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            FirebaseMethods firebaseMethods = new FirebaseMethods(mContext);
                            firebaseMethods.deleteHashtagFromDatabase(title);

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "no",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });


                    alertDialog.show();


        }
    });
```

**Listview is setup like this in my fragment:**

```
private void setupListView(){

    Log.d(TAG, "setupListView: setting up list");
    final ArrayList<HashTag> hashTags = new ArrayList<>();
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_user_hashtags))
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                if(singleSnapshot != null){
                    hashTags.add(0, singleSnapshot.getValue(HashTag.class));
                }

            }

            HashTagListViewAdapter adapter = new HashTagListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_list_itemview, hashTags);
            hashtagListView.setAdapter(adapter);



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Now I have passed the OnClickListener on the subItem from the adapter to the fragment ListView OnItemClickListener as below:

**Updated Adapter**

```
holder.actionIndicator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);



        }
    });
```

**Updated Fragment**

```
hashtagListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {


            long viewId = view.getId();
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: viewId is " + viewId);
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: position is " + position);

            final HashTagListViewAdapter adapter = new HashTagListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_list_itemview, hashTags);
            final HashTag hashTag = hashTags.get(position);
            final String title = hashTag.getTitle();
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: title is " + title);


            if(viewId == R.id.deleteFromListBtn){

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("delete item");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                FirebaseMethods firebaseMethods = new FirebaseMethods(getActivity());
                                firebaseMethods.deleteHashtagFromDatabase(title);
                                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: title is " + title);

                                // NEW PROBLEM HERE!
                                adapter.remove(hashTag);
                                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: removed hashtag is " + hashTag);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: item removed from list.");

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "no",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });


                alertDialog.show();


            }
        }
    });
```

But now the problem is when I delete the item, the listView always delete the last item in the view. However, the correct item was deleted from database and according to the log, this code `adapter.remove(hashTag)` does grab the correct item i intent to delete.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you should not refresh the whole `Fragment`. Bad habit

To refresh your `ListView`,

1. First remove the item from `ArrayList` (named 'hashTags').
2. And just call `YOUR_ADAPTER.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

**notifyDataSetChanged()** will automatically remove item from the `ListView`.

[Use of notifyDataSetChanged()](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html)

Comment: the thing is I need to define the remove action in the adapter's OnClickListener for a sub-item of the listview. So OnClickListener was not set in the listView ItemOnClickListener in the fragment. I have fixed that part, but a new problem shows up. please see my edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should first remove the item from the Database and when success come from the database then item should be removed from ArrayList and the Adapter should be notifiy about the changes made in the ArratList.

To remove item from the ArrayList form adapter class.

```
//postion is the location of item in the arraylist to be deleted.
dataSet.remove(position);
```

now to notifiy the adapter about the changes in the ArrayList. and it should be called which the Adapter class.

```
 notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: the thing is I need to define the remove action in the adapter's OnClickListener for a sub-item of the listview. So OnClickListener was not set in the listView ItemOnClickListener in the fragment. I have fixed that part, but a new problem shows up. please see my edit. Thanks!

Comment: adapter.remove(hashTags.get(position));                   Try it, may be the hashTag store the reference of the last item.

Comment: hey, thanks for the update. I have solved the issue by setting the adapter again after the delete action. `hashtagListView.setAdapter(adapter);` Got the idea from another question, but still don't understand why notifyDataSetChanged won't work...